# How to refer without foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Create two tables:

Course(Course_id(primary key), Course_name)

Student(Roll_no(primary key), Name,Course_id(Foreign key)) and Retrieve the names of all the students who are admitted in the course 'BSC'.

let, the course_id for BSC be 105.

For which the query will be:
SELECT Name FROM Student WHERE Course_id = 105

Can I query for the name of the student without knowing the Course_id (just using the Course_name) ?

Comment: There is no course_name attribute in the student table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an inner join between the tables

```
  SELECT s.Name 
  FROM Student s  
  INNER JOIN Course c on c.course_id  = s.Course_id
  WHERE c.Course_name = 'your_course_name'
```

or using like

```
  SELECT s.Name 
  FROM Student s  
  INNER JOIN Course c on c.course_id  = s.Course_id
  WHERE c.Course_name like 'your_course_name'
```

Comment: What is the difference between using SELECT Name From Student and SELECT s.Name FROM Student s ?

Comment: nothing but it's better to use aliases or fully quantified table names within MySQL @rgo so MySQL can't mix up the columns when subqueries are being used (note not in this query case) i mean in general usage -> in this example you would expect a error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02502/5 for the first query

Answer (score 3):

Or use `WHERE IN (...)`

```
SELECT 
 Student.Name
FROM 
 Student 
WHERE
 Student.Course_id IN (
  SELECT
   Course.cource_id 
  FROM 
   Course
  WHERE
   Course.Name = 'BSC'
)
```

Comment: correct  but IN clause normally produce not so better perfomance as  the innner  ..join  .. anyway upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
SELECT st.Name 
FROM Student st  
INNER JOIN Course c on c.course_id  = st.Course_id
WHERE 
c.Course_name = 'Course_Name';
```